# How to check a date value according to yyyy-mm-dd pattern in bash?

Tags: regex, bash, syntax

In my bash script I want to check that date values provided via command line arguments by the user, have **yyyy-mm-dd** format. So for example, the date **August 10th 2020** has to be written as **2020-08-10**. Here is the test that I've written for pattern matching via a regular expression:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

dateval="2020-08-10"
regexp="^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"

if [[ ! "${dateval}" =~ "${regexp}" ]]
then
    echo "Date format is not valid"
else
    echo "Date format is valid"
fi
```

This prints "Date format **is not valid**" and I don't understand why as the date value being tested is indeed in good format. Could you kindly make some clarification and indicated what I misunderstand?

Comment: The regex should not be quoted so if [[ ! "${dateval}" =~ ${regexp} ]] should work

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: @A.Hristov Thank you very much for your help. This solved the problem. How can I mark your answer as the solution to the question? It seems that I cannot do that by clicking beside your comment.

Comment: @A.Hristov: No need to quote the LHS either: `[[ ! $dateval =~ $regexp ]]` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Even after fixing the code issues, the regex approach would accept dates like 2020-13-99.  I suggest a different approach.  Replace:

```
if [[ ! "${dateval}" =~ "${regexp}" ]]
```

with:

```
if ! date -d "$dateval" +%F >/dev/null 2>&1
```

This will test if the date is actually parseable as a date.  If will, for example, know that `2020-06-30` is valid but `2020-06-31` is invalid.

#### Limiting the acceptable date format

The above accepts any date that is valid and in a format `date` understands.  If we want to require the yyyy-mm-dd format, then use:

```
if [ "$dateval" != "$(date -d "$dateval" +%F 2>/dev/null)" ]
```

Comment: Would still need some combination of regex or parameter expansion as the `date` test alone would accept, e.g. `6/30/2020` or `"next Tuesday"` or any of the other recognized formats instead of just `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin.  I thought that was a feature not a bug but you have a good point.  If we do want to force the date format, we could use `[ "$dateval" != "$(date -d "$dateval" +%F 2>/dev/null)" ]`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot to @A.Hristov  for the help. In fact, the problem was the double quotes that I had put around the regular expression. So here is the correct version of the script which works as expected:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#
#
dateval="2020-08-10"
#
#
regexp="^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}$"
#
#
if [[ ! "${dateval}" =~ ${regexp} ]]
then
    echo "Date format is not valid"
else
    echo "Date format is valid"
fi
```